# Get Default value instead of null while doing KDB select

Tags: kdb

I wanted to get default value when particular  column values is null or blank.

```
e.g select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)
```

returns :

```
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| customer |   date   |  product   | orderId | version | size |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       1 |       6 |      |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       2 |       6 | 1000 |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       3 |       4 |      |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
```

So I want NA instead of blank or null s following :

```
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| customer |   date   |  product   | orderId | version | size |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       1 |       6 |  NA  |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       2 |       6 | 1000 |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       3 |       4 |  NA  |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to do with a value like `NA` because q prefers vectors to be of uniform type. Assuming that your `size` column is a numeric type rather than a symbol you'll run into issues.

I'd advise filling in some numeric value with the [^ fill](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fill/) operator. For example, to fill in zero as the default value:

```
q)res:select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)
q)update 0^size from res
customer date     product    orderId version size
-------------------------------------------------
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 1       6       0  
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 2       6       1000
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 3       4       0
```

If it's important to use the `NA` value then you can cast the column to symbol type and fill with `` `NA ``:

```
q)res:select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)
q)update `NA^`$string size from res
customer date     product    orderId version size
-------------------------------------------------
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 1       6       NA  
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 2       6       1000
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 3       4       NA
```

The downside of doing this is that you will no longer be able to do numeric operations on the column without first casting back to a numeric type:

```
q)select sum size from res
'type
  [0]  select sum size from res
q)select sum "J"$string size from res
size
----
1000
```

Comment: suppose if data type is string then how to do it ? Is it possible in one query ?

Comment: If the `size` column is already a string (string, not symbol) then you can do the same casting above, but without needing the string function: ``update `NA^`$size from res``. If you want to do this without creating the intermediate `res` table then you can cast and fill directly in the original select statement ``select customer,date,product,orderId,version,`NA^`$size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)``